# Best way to connect react to php

Tags: php, node.js, reactjs

I am wondering what is the best way to connect backend wrote in php to front end code in ReactJS.

What is an option for that idea?

I am sure that when application have on backend laravel then I can use laravel-mix to use react on frontend, but is there any alternatives?

Maybe implement react to symfony, CakePHP or maybe just only simple **PHP** can run react on frontend.

I'm working on **react** application right now it is running on **nodeJS** but It is important for me to use **PHP** and **MySQL** on backend.

So I am looking for the easiest and cleanest solution.
Thank You for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should separate your frontend and backend stacks, with a REST interface in between. With the architecture, you will have more control of your both frontend and backend to choose your favorite tools, languages etc. For instance, you can work on React.js + Webpack + Babel for your frontend and Laravel / Symfony for the backend.

Please see this [article](https://quickleft.com/blog/six-reasons-we-split-front-end-and-back-end-code-into-two-git-repositories-working-with-github-repositories/) with more details and advantages of doing this way.

Answer (score 1):

it is easy 
this  is very clean explaining with example and steps [enter link description here](https://reactnativecode.com/react-native-user-registration-example-tutorial/)

```js
 
fetch('https://reactnativecode.000webhostapp.com/user_registration.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
 
    name: UserName,
 
    email: UserEmail,
 
    password: UserPassword
 
  })
 
}).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
 
// Showing response message coming from the server after inserting records.
        Alert.alert(responseJson);
 
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
 
 
  }
```

```
fetch('https://reactnativecode.000webhostapp.com/user_registration.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({

    name: UserName,

    email: UserEmail,

    password: UserPassword

  })

}).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

// Showing response message coming from the server after inserting records.
        Alert.alert(responseJson);

      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
}
```